# (AdWords Script) Saving spreadsheet to specified Google Drive folder

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get the newly created spreadsheet into a specified folder through the variable "datedFolder". Can someone assist me with this? The code is as follow.

```
var folderName = 'Performance_Folder';
var myAccounts = ['xxxx','yyyyy'];

function main() {
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var datedFolder = myFolder.createFolder(formattedDate);
  var accountSelector = MccApp.accounts();
  if (myAccounts.length > 0) {
    accountSelector = accountSelector.withIds(myAccounts);
  }
  accountSelector.withLimit(50).executeInParallel('runOnEachAccount');
}

function runOnEachAccount() {
  Logger.log('Starting on: '+AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId());
  var results = getAccountReport();
  Logger.log(results);
  return JSON.stringify(results);
}

function getAccountReport() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId());
  var report = AdWordsApp.report(
  "SELECT CampaignName, AdGroupName, KeywordText, QualityScore " +
  " FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT " +
  " WHERE " +
  " QualityScore < 5" +
  " AND Impressions > 0" +
  " DURING LAST_7_DAYS");
  report.exportToSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet());
  Logger.log("Report available at " + spreadsheet.getUrl());
}
```

Greatly appreciated. Thanks!